# How to hide description on Image type

Tags: plone

I would like to hide the description for all Images. Is there a way to do this in a product, without recreating the image type?

Comment: Do you mean in folder listings? Or, in image tags where images are in the content?

Comment: I meant image "types".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most pragmatic way would be to hide it via CSS.